# showing the length of a input

Tags: javascript, html

How do I enable input2 if enable 1 has input within it (basically re-enabling it), I'm still a beginner and have no idea to do this.

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" id="text1" onkeyup="valid()">
    <input type="text" id="text2" disabled="disabled">
    <script language="javascript">
        function valid() {
            var firstTag = document.getElementById("text1").length;
            var min = 1;

            if (firstTag > min)
            //if the text entered is longer than 1 alert to screen
            {
                //enable the text2 tag  
            }

        }
        //once input from text1 is entered launch this function
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("text2").removeAttribute("disabled") ?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly, you want to enable the second input as long as the first input have value in it?

then use dom to change the disabled state of that input

```
if(firstTag > min)
//if the text entered is longer than 1 alert to screen
{
  //enable the text2 tag  
  document.getElementById("text2").disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

```js
var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
text1.onchange = function () {
   if (this.value != "" || this.value.length > 0) {
      document.getElementById("text2").disabled = false;
   } else {
     document.getElementById("text2").disabled = true;
   }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="text" id="text2" disabled="disabled">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `.value` to get the value. And, then test its `.length`. That is `firstTag` should be:

```
var firstTag = document.getElementById("text1").value.length;
```

And, the complete function should be:

```
function valid() {
    var min = 1;
    var firstTag = document.getElementById("text1");
    var secondTag = document.getElementById("text2");

    if (firstTag.length > min) {
        secondTag.disabled = false
    } else {
        secondTag.disabled = true
    }
}
```

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to correct your code "**document.getElementById("text1").length**" to "**document.getElementById("text1").value.length**".

Second, there are two ways you can remove disabled property.

1) **Jquery** - $('#text2').prop('disabled', false);

2) **Javascript** - document.getElementById("text2").disabled = false;

Below is the example using javascript,

```js
function valid() {
  var firstTag = document.getElementById("text1").value.length;
  var min = 1;

  if (firstTag > min) {
    document.getElementById("text2").disabled = false;
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("text2").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1" onkeyup="valid()">
<input type="text" id="text2" disabled="disabled">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.disabled` property of the second element. It is a boolean property (true/false).

Also note that you need to use `.value` to retrieve the text of an input element.

Demo:

```js
function valid() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text1").value;
  var minLength = 1;
  document.getElementById("text2").disabled = text.length < minLength;
}

valid(); // run it at least once on start
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1" onkeyup="valid()">
<input type="text" id="text2">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just change @Korat code  event to keyup like this:

```html
<div>
<input type="text" id="in1" onkeyup="enablesecond()";/>
<input type="text" id="in2" disabled="true"/>
</div>
<script>


var text1 = document.getElementById("in1");
text1.onkeyup = function () {
   if (this.value != "" || this.value.length > 0) {
      document.getElementById("in2").disabled = false;
   } else {
     document.getElementById("in2").disabled = true;
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create my own so that I could automate this for more than just two inputs although the output is always set to null, is it that I cannot give text2's id from text1?

```
<div id="content">
            <form id="form1">
            <input type="text" id="text1" onkeyup="valid(this.id,text2)">
            <input type="text" id="text2" disabled="disabled">


            <script language ="javascript">

                function valid(firstID,secondID){
                    var firstTag = document.getElementById(firstID).value.length;
                    var min = 0;

                    if(firstTag > min)
                    //if the text entered is longer than 1 alert to screen
                    {
                        document.getElementById(secondID).disabled = false;
                    }
                    if(firstTag == 0){
                        document.getElementById(secondID).disabled = true;
                       } 
                }
                //once input from text1 is entered launch this function 
            </script>

            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you are asking is how to remove the `disabled` attribute  (*enable*) from the second input when more than 1 character has been entered into the first input field.

You can to use the `oninput` event. This will call your function every time a new character is added to the first input field. Then you just need to set the second input field's `disabled` attribute to false.

Here is a working example.

[Run this example at Repl.it](https://repl.it/@KevinWelch/EnableOnInput)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <!-- Call enableInput2 on input event -->
    <input id="input1" oninput="enableInput2()">
    <input id="input2" disabled>

    <script>
    function enableInput2() {
        // get the text from the input1 field
        var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
        if (input1.length > 1) {
            // enable input2 by setting disabled attribute to 'false'
            document.getElementById("input2").disabled = false;
        } else {
            // disable input2 once there is 1 or less characters in input1
            document.getElementById("input2").disabled = true;
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: It is better practice to use `addEventListener` instead of putting event handlers (e.g. `onclick`, `oninput`, etc.) directly into HTML.